# YouTube can't see Chromecast after setup

Tags: streaming, youtube, video-streaming, chromecast

I successfully paired my Chromecast to my Android devices.  My Android devices are synced with my Google account, and I would have expected immediate access via Youtube on logged-in PC browsers.  However, Youtube is providing the following inapplicable instructions:

[image]

Specifically, I have neither a "YouTube app" on my TV nor a game console, I have a Chromecast.  How can I pair both my Android devices as well as my PC browsers with the Chromecast device?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, the way [Chromecast works](https://support.google.com/chromecast/answer/2995235?hl=en) is that you must use Chrome and install the [Google Cast](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/google-cast/boadgeojelhgndaghljhdicfkmllpafd) extension from the Chrome store.

YouTube's "Connected TVs" uses a different and evidently incompatible technology for TVs and game console YouTube apps to make YouTube universally aware of these devices as long as you're logged in.  Your YouTube account appears to be completely unaware that you have a Chromecast, and it's just the Google Cast Chrome extension that does its magic.